# Jquery and clone tables not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a 2 external jquery files one allows me to clone the last row of a table while the other should allow me to grab the id of select tag based on a class assigned to it. However it only works for the original row and does not work when i clone the rows. Any help would be greatly appreacated.

Js to clone last table row:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn_AddTruck").click(function () {
               var $tableBody = $('#tbl_invTruck').find("tbody"),
                $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
                $trNew = $trLast.clone();
                // Find by attribute 'id'
                $trNew.find('[id]').each(function () {
                    var num = this.id.replace(/\D/g, '');
                    if (!num) {
                        num = 0;
                    }
                    // Remove numbers by first regexp
                    this.id = this.id.replace(/\d/g, '') 
                        // increment number
                        + (1 + parseInt(num, 10));
                });

                $trLast.after($trNew); 

            });
        });
```

Js to get id of select tag by class:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(function(ready){
   $('.selectLp').change(function() {
     //alert("working" +this.id);
     var Lp_Id = this.id;
     alert(Lp_Id);
    });
 });
})
```

Comment: Could you also put the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating clone or adding dynamically to DOM you need to change

```
$('.selectLp').change(function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on('change','.selectLp',function(){
```